# valgrind reports getpwuid() leaks in c++ with Ubuntu

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, ubuntu-12.04, getpwuid

I have the following C++ file, pwd01.cpp:

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <iostream>
int main() {        
    passwd* pwd = getpwuid(getuid());
}
```

I compile this with the following command:

```
g++ pwd01.cpp -Wall -o pwd01
```

On Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS / gcc version 4.6.3, valgrind reports a leak (see below). When I compile the same code with the same command on Mac OS 10.6.8 / gcc version 4.2.1, valgrind reports no leaks.

I am aware that I do not need to free passwd* ( [should I free pointer returned by getpwuid() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160290/should-i-free-pointer-returned-by-getpwuid-in-linux) ); so what am I missing?

```
valgrind ./pwd01
==10618== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10618== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10618== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10618== Command: ./pwd01
==10618== 
==10618== 
==10618== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10618==     in use at exit: 300 bytes in 11 blocks
==10618==   total heap usage: 68 allocs, 57 frees, 10,130 bytes allocated
==10618== 
==10618== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10618==    definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks
==10618==    indirectly lost: 240 bytes in 10 blocks
==10618==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10618==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10618==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10618== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10618== 
==10618== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10618== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Does not seem to be a "real" leak, i.e., if called several times, the leak doesn't compound; probably it holds a static pointer to a memory area, if it is NULL (the first time) it allocates those 60 bytes, and then doesn't free them up.

The MacOS X version either uses a truly static area, or its `valgrind` has got better [suppressors](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress).

Just run the `getpwuid` a couple hundred times in a loop to ensure it really leaks only 60 bytes (and not 1200), just to be sure.

**UPDATE**

I have finally tracked the leak to several structures inside `nssswitch.c` and `getXXent.c`, of different sizes and persuasions. While the code seems to make many more allocations than really necessary, needing malloc locks, this shouldn't be usually appreciable performance-wise, and I for one surely do **not** intend to second-guess *the maintainers of glibc*!

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that running it in a loop 1000 times does not compound the leak: the LEAK SUMMARY is the same as before (60 bytes definitely lost); the HEAP SUMMARY then shows: total heap usage: 1,067 allocs, 1,056 frees, 577,562 bytes allocated

Answer (score 0):

It may not be `getpwuid()` itself that is causing that (false) positive. It could be any number of other things that the C library initializes at start up time, but then doesn't tear down at process termination (because the process is going away, along with all the mapped memory that belongs to it, some things don't really need to be destructed/unallocated). As another answer said, run some additional tests, especially as you build more code beyond the simple example you provided, and make sure the numbers are stable, and not directly attributable to your own code. There's not much you can do about the library code directly, except submit a bug report (I'm assuming you're not one of the C library developers, anyway).